# How do I filter data using date in angularjs2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular2-pipe

I have set of json formated string and need to filter data using date. It is like filter All dates, Last 3 months and Last 6 months using angular2.
Please find the below structure and I need filtered data using date.

```
<ul>
   <li*ngFor="let account of activities">
      {{accont.activityDate | date}} - {{account.activityDescription}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

My Json data is:

```
"activities": [
{
  "activityDate": "2016-07-02",
  "activityDescription": "Data1",
},
{
  "activityDate": "2016-08-23",
  "activityDescription": "Data2",
},
{
  "activityDate": "2016-04-11",
  "activityDescription": "Data3",
}
{
  "activityDate": "2016-04-11",
  "activityDescription": "Data4",
}
{
  "activityDate": "2015-07-21",
  "activityDescription": "Data5",
}
];
```

```js
"activities": [{
  "activityDate": "2016-07-02",
  "activityDescription": "Data1",
}, {
  "activityDate": "2016-08-23",
  "activityDescription": "Data2",
}, {
  "activityDate": "2016-04-11",
  "activityDescription": "Data3",
} {
  "activityDate": "2016-04-11",
  "activityDescription": "Data4",
} {
  "activityDate": "2015-07-21",
  "activityDescription": "Data5",
}];
```

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let account of activities">
    {{accont.activityDate | date}} - {{account.activityDescription}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

the date pipe helps you to format date, not to filter it.

you should pass a set of filtered activities according to your criteria.
therefore, write something like:

```
<ul>
  <li*ngFor="let account of filteredActivities">
     {{accont.activityDate | date}} - {{account.activityDescription}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and in your component

```
private filteredActivities;
private dateLimit = new Date().getTime() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 30 days ago ... define as and where you wish

filterActivities() {
   return this.activities.filter(activity => {
      let date:Date = new Date(activity.activityDate);
      return date.getTime() > dateLimitInMS;
   });
}
```

you could call set the filteredActivities in ngInit and on change of the dateLimit.

*dont write a custom pipe and dont pass the filteredActivities function itself, the angular team explains why*
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filter-pipe

edit: here is a select where you have a list of limits and an event fired when you select something.. use this event to set the new value of filteredActivities.

```
<select (change)="onLimitChange($event)">
   <option *ngFor="let limit of limits" [value]="limit.value">
      {{limit.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Oliver Renner, Thanks for the answer. I have one another implementation need to do for this using selected item in dropdown list. Can you have any idea to how to do this.

Comment: i edited my previous answer and added the select... code need adaption but you should get the meaning.